# create dataframe by randomly sampling from multiple files

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a folder with several 20 million record tab delimited files in it.  I would like to create a pandas dataframe where I randomly sample say 20 thousand records from each file, and then append them together in the dataframe.  Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could read in all the text files in a particular folder.  Then you could make use of pandas `Dataframe.sample` ([link to docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html)).

I've provided a fully reproducible example with two example .txt file created with 200 rows.  I then take a random sample of ten rows and append the sample to a final datframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

# Change the path for the directory
directory = r'C:\some\example\folder'
# I create two test .txt files for demonstration purposes with 200 rows each
df_test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(200, 2), columns=list('AB'))
df_test.to_csv(directory + r'\test_1.txt', sep='\t', index=False)
df_test.to_csv(directory + r'\test_2.txt', sep='\t', index=False)

df = pd.DataFrame()

for filename in glob.glob(directory + r'\*.txt'):
    df_full = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t')
    df_sample = df_full.sample(n=10)
    df = df.append(df_sample)
```